# error C2143: syntax error missing ')' before 'constant'

Tags: c++

I'm a student using c++ in class.  I did see this error in about three other questions, however, they were all solved by adding a basic arithmetic sign in front of a hard-coded number.  As I'm not doing arithmetic, I don't think they will help me here.

For our assignment we're having to parse a bibliography and store the resulting entries into a linked list of entries.  To that end, the book we're using has a linked list class, but it has errors.  One of the error sets I can't figure out is:

- "error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before 'constant.'
- "error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'constant.'
- "error C2059: syntax error: missing ')'
- "error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

The offending line(s) are in a template header, and my question is what can I do to fix this?
The code can be found here:

```
template <class DataType>
class LinkedList : public AbstractLinkedList<DataType>{
protected:
    DataType* _info;
    LinkedList<DataType>* _next;
    void copy(const LinkedList<DataType>& 11);  //first offending line
public:
    LinkedList();
    LinkedList(const LinkedList<DataType>& ll);
    LinkedList(const DataType& info);
    LinkedList(const DataType& info, LinkedList<DataType>* next);
    ~LinkedList();
};

template <class DataType>
void LinkedList<DataType>::copy(const LinkedList<DataType>& 11){  //second offending line
    if(ll._info == NULL){
        _info = NULL;
    } else {
        _info = new DataType(*(ll._info));
        if(_info == NULL){
            throw LinkedListMemory();
        }
    }
    if(ll._next == NULL){
        _next = NULL;
    } else {
        _next = new LinkedList<DataType>(*(ll._next));
        if(_next == NULL){
            throw LinkedListMemory();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm skipping over parts that aren't causing errors

Things I've tried:

- changing the name from "copy" to something like "copyList"
- removing the const keyword;
- removing "LinkedList<" and ">"
- removing "<""DataType>"

none of that fixed the problem and my understanding is without the "LinkedList'<'DataType>&" it can't really be used in a template form.

Comment: Identifiers can't start with digits. `11` starts with a digit.

Comment: 11 is not legal variable name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`11` (the number one, twice) is not a valid variable name; identifiers must start with a letter or underscore.

You probably meant `ll` (the letter "l", twice, which could stand for "linked list"). It can be hard to distinguish `l` from `1` in some fonts.

Comment: And that's why you usually want to write code in an editor which has syntax highlighting.

Comment: It's also why using explanatory variable names instead of shortened letters is a good idea. It's not 1970 anymore, there's no need to conserve screen scape like that!

Answer (score 0):

Variable names cannot start with numbers, because a string of digits would be a valid identifier as well as a valid number.